# Select Option opens unique Text Box

Tags: html, forms, select, textbox

I want to have two different select options which have, let's say, options such as EMAIL or PHONE NUMBER, and when you select the EMAIL option a text box opens below it that says "Enter Email" or when you select PHONE NUMBER option a different text box opens below it that says "Enter Phone #:".

Ps. I don't want both text boxes showing at one time, I want them to select which one to fill. If you have a better way of doing this, please let me know your ideas.

```
<form action="order-step4.php" method="post"> 

    Please fill out these fields:<br /> 
    Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient" /><br />

    Recipient Email: <input type="text" name="remail" /><br /> 

    Recipient Cell: <input type="text" name="rsms" /><br /> 

    Your Message :<input type="text" name="message" /><br /> 

    <input type="submit"> 
 </form>
```

Thank you,
Chad.

Comment: please post what you have tried till now

Comment: Right now all I have is the two textbox's that send to the database, but I want them to select which one, as so they aren't confused if they have to enter both or not, etc. And for fluidity.

Comment: code please,which you have tried

Comment: `code`<form action="order-step4.php" method="post">
Please fill out these fields:<br />
Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient" /><br />
Recipient Email: <input type="text" name="remail" /><br />
Recipient Cell: <input type="text" name="rsms" /><br />
Your Message :<input type="text" name="message" /><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>`code`

Watered down example of the code I have currently.

Answer (score 0):

Have a drop down option for selecting Phone or Email,and show/hide respective input textbox on dropdown change.

```
<select id="myChoice">
  <option value="email">Email</option>
  <option value="phone">Phone</option>
</select>
```

here is function

```
$('#myChoice').change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() === 'email') {
           //show email
           //hide phone

        } else {
            //hide email
           //show phone
        }
});
```

Comment: I have not tested this out, I will right away just busy with some other codes on the site. Will this work on phone devices? Such as iPhone, etc.

Comment: are you using phonegap or related technology,casue it surely not a objective c code?

Comment: Not using anything like phonegap, just normal PHP CSS xHTML.

Comment: Now all I need is to get that if ($(this).val() === 'email') { is TRUE then it shows ENTER EMAIL text box... and if it's FALSE (else) it will show the ENTER PHONE text box..?

Comment: I want it so that if they select Email from the dropdown then it ONLY shows the Enter Email: text box and if they select the Phone it ONLY shows the Enter Phone: text box.